# failed to find build tool version 25.0.3

Tags: android

In android studio when the gradle sync process starts the error pops up that "failed to build tool version 25.0.3". Then I installed the 25.0.3 build tool but after installation [build tool version error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfqgv.jpg)

These error came up I tried to find out solution on stackoverflow but I didn't find anything useful. I also tried to use lower build version but nothing happened same errors are appearing [after installing build tool version 25.0.3 these errors are popped up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqiZN.jpg)

I don't understand how to solve. looking forward for help. thanx

Comment: Did you try to clean the project? Could you post your gradle file?

Comment: connect charger, connect internet and then download missing library from sdk manager

Comment: @JaydeepPatel Oh well, nice one! :) The missing internet connection should be the problem lol :D

Comment: open sdk manager and click on sdk tools and check Android SDK Build-tools 25.0.3 is installed or not.

Comment: yeah thank u for the solution.it was due to the bad internet connection-

Comment: yeah my firewall was blocking the connection

Answer (score 1):

I see you found a solution already but just in case someone else is facing this problem:

I just bumped into this issue, I was importing an app with `buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"` and getting the same error you show. What I did is changed it to `25.0.1`, sync gradle and then bump it to `25.0.3` and it's working now.